# Multiple runtime exceptions when using string array in C# for unknown reason

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, lexer, indexoutofrangeexception

I am writing a lexer, or tokenizer, for a programming language. One of the main functions is to split the line of source code into "tokens". I am achieving this by splitting on spaces to create string arrays. Therefore, when I want to preserve strings, I must temporarily change the contents to a keyword while the line is split, and then put the strings back in afterwards. This worked until I developed the variable system for the language, and I had to be able to preserve multiple strings. Then all exception hell broke loose.

Exceptions:

NullReferenceException (line 12) `subStringArg[ini] = quotes[1];`

IndexOutOfRangeException (line 34) `value = value.Replace("STRING", subStringArg[ini]);`

Minimum reproducible example:

```cs
public static string[] LexLine(string line)
        {
            string[] subStringArg = null;
            string[] quotes = null;
            string[] tokens = null;
            int ini = 0; // Random name
            while (line.Contains('\"'))
            {
                if (line.Contains('\"'))
                {
                    quotes = line.Split('\"');
                    subStringArg[ini] = quotes[1];
                }

                if (subStringArg != null)
                {
                    line = line.Replace(quotes[1], "STRING");
                    line = line.Replace("\\", "");
                    line = line.Replace("\"", "");
                }
                ini++;
            }
            tokens = line.Split(' ');
            if (tokens[0] == "Output" && tokens[1] != "STRING")
            {
                tokens[1] = IO.OutputVariable(tokens[1]);
            }
            ini = 0;
            foreach (string i in tokens)
            {
                if (i == "STRING" && subStringArg != null)
                {
                    string value = i;
                    value = value.Replace("STRING", subStringArg[ini]);
                    tokens[currentArrayEntry] = value;
                }
                currentArrayEntry++;
                ini++;
            }
            return tokens;
        }
```

Source code (from my lang):

```
Output "Defining variables..." to Console. // Exception thrown here
New string of name "sampleStringVar" with value "sample".
Output "enter your name:" to Console.
Get input.
Output sampleStringVar to Console.
```

I'm asking here because I am clueless as what to do. I should not be getting a NullReferenceException from *assigning* values.

Comment: Where you initialize `subStringArg`?

Comment: I think the time has come for you to learn to debug. Watch a couple of video's on YouTube to get the hang of stepping through code. The first error: NullReferenceException is because the subStringArg[ini] hasn't been initialized. The second error IndexOutOfRangeException  is because subStringArg[ini] is an array with less items than the **ini** value.

Comment: Not where I initialize, where I assign the value of `quotes[1]` to `subStringArg[ini]`. also I must clarify that when I debugged, the value of `quotes[1]` had a value.

Comment: Jeremy in C# values in an array can be added without being initialized. I also made sure `ini = 0` before line 34. When the exception is thrown, `quotes[1]` is not null, the only null variables are `subStringArg` and `tokens`, and `ini` = `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the following

```
string[] subStringArg = null;
```

then later you do this

```
subStringArg[ini] = quotes[1];
```

But you have not initialised `subStringArg` so it is still null, so you can't assign anything to it and you will get a `NullReferenceError`

You must first initialise your array before you can assign anything into it.

Also, you should not assume that you have a value in `quotes[1]` without first checking it.  This will lead to a `IndexOutOfRangeException`

As another point.  The first `If` statement inside your while loop checks for the same condition as the while loop, so it will always be true!

So the following would be better

```
string[] subStringArg = new String[enterKnownLengthHere_OrUseALIst];
...
 while (line.Contains('\"'))
 {
        quotes = line.Split('\"');
        if(quotes != null && quotes.Length >= 2)
            subStringArg[ini] = quotes[1];
        else
           //Error handling here!


        if (subStringArg.Length >= 1)
        {
                line = line.Replace(quotes[1], "STRING");
                line = line.Replace("\\", "");
                line = line.Replace("\"", "");
        }
        ini++;
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer, OP I still highly recommend you learn how to use a debugger, the IDE shows you this. You don't know what you're missing out on!